# how to find which user use which version in playconsole?can we find their machine id or their name?

Tags: android, ios

how to find which user use which version in playconsole?can we find their machine id or their name?

iam try to find that which version use which user. cause to notify old user for updation and user use new version easily

Comment: I don't know specifically about Android, but you could have a WebAPI that tell you which is the last app version that is "supported", and make a pop-up at start if the your current version is lower that than one to tell them to update before continuing to use the app? I guess you could ask the Playstore which version is the last, but you might not want necessarily to update all user to the last one (ie, the last version is for little improvements, but the previous one is a big fix and need to at least used by all users).